# What is the best way to stop Uvicorn server programmatically?

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn

In Docker, I run uvicorn with bootstrap.sh & command line. In code there is a condition about public key file, if exception occurs, server needs to shutdown.

So what I want to do in main.py is here (It is FastAPI).

```py
public_key = None

try:
    with open(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE) as public_key_file:
        public_key = public_key_file.read()
except Exception as f_error:
    logger.exception(f_error)
    module = util.find_spec("uvicorn")

    if module:
        uvicorn = import_module('uvicorn')
        uvicorn.stop() # what I want to do
```

However, I couldn't find a way to shutdown uvicorn server programmatically. What would be the best approach?

Comment: Raising an exception  (or re-raising `f_error`) inside your `except` clause would terminate the current application unless there's another level of exception handling outside of this code. Would that work?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes it works and it actually a quite good work around, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start a Uvicorn + FastAPI in background when testing with PyTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412825/how-to-start-a-uvicorn-fastapi-in-background-when-testing-with-pytest)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57412825/1032286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raising an exception (or re-raising f_error) inside your except clause would terminate the current application unless there's another level of exception handling outside of the code you've included.

When the python interpreter receives a top level exception (i.e. one that isn't caught by `except`), the interpreter terminates. You can use this to shut down your script and trigger your container runtime to restart the application as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Gracefully Shutting Down Uvicorn running FastAPI Application

The key libraries to achieve graceful shutting down to a Uvicorn server running a FastAPI application are the built in `os` and `signal` modules.
Given an endpoint with which a client can request the server to shutdown.

```py
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
```

`os.getpid()` retrieves the running process' system ID and then `signal.SIGINT` is passed to the process to signal an interrupt.
SIGTERM and SIGINT can be used to achieve the same result.

Links:

- [os.kill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill)
- [SIGINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGINT)

```py
import os
import signal
import fastapi
import uvicorn

app = fastapi.FastAPI()

def hello():
    return fastapi.Response(status_code=200, content='Hello, world!')

def shutdown():
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
    return fastapi.Response(status_code=200, content='Server shutting down...')

@app.on_event('shutdown')
def on_shutdown():
    print('Server shutting down...')

app.add_api_route('/hello', hello, methods=['GET'])
app.add_api_route('/shutdown', shutdown, methods=['GET'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=8000)
```

```py
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(requests.get('http://localhost:8000/hello').content)
    print(requests.get('http://localhost:8000/shutdown').content)
```

https://gist.github.com/BnJam/8123540b1716c81922169fa4f7c43cf0

Answer (score 1):

I need to terminate the backend FastAPI service when an environment variable is missing. With gunicorn I use **sys.exit(4)**:

```
try:
   DB_CONN = os.environ["DB_CONN"]

except Exception as e:
   print(f"Missing env variable value for {e}. Terminating.")
   sys.exit(4)
```

Here is the result in Docker:

[image]