# How to terminate a Uvicorn + FastAPI application cleanly with workers >= 2 when testing with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, uvicorn

I have an application written with Uvicorn + FastAPI.
I am testing the response time using PyTest.

Referring to [How to start a Uvicorn + FastAPI in background when testing with PyTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412825/how-to-start-a-uvicorn-fastapi-in-background-when-testing-with-pytest), I wrote the test.
However, I found the application process alive after completing the test when workers >= 2.

I want to terminate the application process cleanly at the end of the test.

Do you have any idea?

The details are as follows.

### Environment

- Windows 10
- Bash 4.4.23 (https://cmder.net/)
- python 3.7.5

#### Libraries

- fastapi == 0.68.0
- uvicorn == 0.14.0
- requests == 2.26.0
- pytest == 6.2.4

### Sample Codes

- Application: main.py

  ```py
  from fastapi import FastAPI

  app = FastAPI()

  @app.get("/")
  def hello_world():
      return "hello world"
  ```
- Test: test_main.py

  ```py
  from multiprocessing import Process
  import pytest
  import requests
  import time
  import uvicorn

  HOST = "127.0.0.1"
  PORT = 8765
  WORKERS = 1


  def run_server(host: str, port: int, workers: int, wait: int = 15) -> Process:
      proc = Process(
          target=uvicorn.run,
          args=("main:app",),
          kwargs={
              "host": host,
              "port": port,
              "workers": workers,
          },
      )
      proc.start()
      time.sleep(wait)
      assert proc.is_alive()
      return proc


  def shutdown_server(proc: Process):
      proc.terminate()
      for _ in range(5):
          if proc.is_alive():
              time.sleep(5)
          else:
              return
      else:
          raise Exception("Process still alive")


  def check_response(host: str, port: int):
      assert requests.get(f"http://{host}:{port}").text == '"hello world"'


  def check_response_time(host: str, port: int, tol: float = 1e-2):
      s = time.time()
      requests.get(f"http://{host}:{port}")
      e = time.time()
      assert e-s < tol


  @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
  def server():
      proc = run_server(HOST, PORT, WORKERS)
      try:
          yield
      finally:
          shutdown_server(proc)


  def test_main(server):
      check_response(HOST, PORT)
      check_response_time(HOST, PORT)
      check_response(HOST, PORT)
      check_response_time(HOST, PORT)
  ```

### Execution Result

```sh
$ curl http://localhost:8765
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8765: Connection refused
$ pytest test_main.py
=============== test session starts =============== platform win32 -- Python 3.7.5, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: .\
collected 1 item

test_main.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                                         [100%]

=============== 1 passed in 20.23s ===============
$ curl http://localhost:8765
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8765: Connection refused
$ sed -i -e "s/WORKERS = 1/WORKERS = 3/g" test_main.py
$ curl http://localhost:8765
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8765: Connection refused
$ pytest test_main.py
=============== test session starts =============== platform win32 -- Python 3.7.5, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: .\
collected 1 item

test_main.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                                         [100%]

=============== 1 passed in 20.21s ===============
$ curl http://localhost:8765
"hello world"

$ # Why is localhost:8765 still alive?
```

Comment: This is a related version of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61577643/4165272 issue.

Comment: I use **sys.exit(4)**. Here are the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74117959/1689733

Comment: I use **sys.exit(4)**
[Here are more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74117959/1689733)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution myself.

Thanks > https://stackoverflow.com/a/27034438/16567832

### Solution

After install psutil by `pip install psutil`, update test_main.py

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import psutil
import pytest
import requests
import time
import uvicorn

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 8765
WORKERS = 3


def run_server(host: str, port: int, workers: int, wait: int = 15) -> Process:
    proc = Process(
        target=uvicorn.run,
        args=("main:app",),
        kwargs={
            "host": host,
            "port": port,
            "workers": workers,
        },
    )
    proc.start()
    time.sleep(wait)
    assert proc.is_alive()
    return proc


def shutdown_server(proc: Process):

    ##### SOLUTION #####
    pid = proc.pid
    parent = psutil.Process(pid)
    for child in parent.children(recursive=True):
        child.kill()
    ##### SOLUTION END ####

    proc.terminate()
    for _ in range(5):
        if proc.is_alive():
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            return
    else:
        raise Exception("Process still alive")


def check_response(host: str, port: int):
    assert requests.get(f"http://{host}:{port}").text == '"hello world"'


def check_response_time(host: str, port: int, tol: float = 1e-2):
    s = time.time()
    requests.get(f"http://{host}:{port}")
    e = time.time()
    assert e-s < tol


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def server():
    proc = run_server(HOST, PORT, WORKERS)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        shutdown_server(proc)


def test_main(server):
    check_response(HOST, PORT)
    check_response_time(HOST, PORT)
    check_response(HOST, PORT)
    check_response_time(HOST, PORT)
```

### Execution Result

```sh
$ curl http://localhost:8765
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8765: Connection refused
$ pytest test_main.py
================== test session starts ================== platform win32 -- Python 3.7.5, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: .\
collected 1 item

test_main.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                                         [100%]

================== 1 passed in 20.24s ==================
$ curl http://localhost:8765
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8765: Connection refused
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object

Comment: @WolfgangFahl thanks comment. May I ask you two questions?
1. in which environment did you try the solution? 2. where was the error raised? In my environment, which is written above, my solution still works.

Comment: 1. MacOS. 2. justpy CI tests

Answer (score 1):

**Follow up of [@hmasdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16567832/hmasdev) answer**

```
import os
import fastapi
import uvicorn
import psutil

    @app.get("/quit")
    def iquit():
        parent_pid = os.getpid()
        parent = psutil.Process(parent_pid)
        for child in parent.children(recursive=True):  # or parent.children() for recursive=False
            child.kill()
        parent.kill()
    
    
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        uvicorn.run(app, port=36113, host='127.0.0.1')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).